# Disable Select Box option after its creation

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a select box that is dynamically created from a mySQL database and then afterwards I use a function to add a "Please Select" option at Index[0] then I force Index[0] to be the selected option. My problem is trying to figure out how to make Index[0] disabled after the fact of its creation or maybe I have to do it during its creation in my function.  So at the end of the day the "Please Select" option is not a valid choose-able option.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
 <?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","karaoke");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $sql = "Select * FROM regulars ORDER BY Regulars ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Bad SQL: $sql");
  $opt = "<select id = 'regulars' name = 'regulars'>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $opt .= "<option value'{$row['Regulars']}'>{$row['Regulars']}</option>\n";
   }
 $opt .="</select>"
 ?>

 <center><div>
 <?php
 echo $opt;
 ?>

 </div></center>

 <script>
  function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("regulars");
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.text = "Please Select";
   x.add(option, x[0]);
  }
  </script>

  <script>
  myFunction()
  document.getElementById("regulars").selectedIndex = "0";
  </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `disabled` attribute to `true` for the newly created option.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("regulars");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = "Please Select";
  option.disabled = true;
  x.add(option, x[0]);
}

myFunction();
document.getElementById("regulars").selectedIndex = "0";
```

```html
<select id="regulars">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: TYSM that works great wow all that research and testing different things helps me learn but the answer was so simple and elegant that I am embarassed lol...Thanks again bro

Comment: @TotalNoob -- Glad to help. Please accept this answer if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to do everything in PHP. No need of all the js to add the option. 
The plus is that it will be part of the DOM and it will be easier to manipulate it later (i.e. to remove the disabled)

```
 <?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","karaoke");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $sql = "Select * FROM regulars ORDER BY Regulars ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Bad SQL: $sql");
  $opt = "<select id = 'regulars' name = 'regulars'>";
  $opt .= "<option value=\"\" disabled>Please select...</option>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $opt .= "<option value'{$row['Regulars']}'>{$row['Regulars']}</option>\n";
   }
 $opt .="</select>"
 ?>
```

Comment: tganks for your response I have tried that before as well but gave up because I kept getting this error:  
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" disabled>Please select...</o' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\karaoke\addsinger.php on line 38

Comment: right, it is beacuse of the double quotes for value. Replace with single quotes or escape it

Comment: ahhh dang it I should have seen that duh...tried and that works...thanks alot for the extra option.